# How to create a Gmail like layout with Twitter Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to create a GMail-like layout using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0, so that the layout always fits to the viewport (window height) and the sidebar as well as the content area are separately scrollable?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                        |
|                    Fixed top navbar                                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         |                                                              |   
| Sidebar |       Content area scrollable                                |
| scrollable                                                             |
|         |                                                              |
|         |                                                              |
|         |                                                              |
|         |                                                              |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

**P/S**: Funny that of all the examples on the Bootstrap 3.0 site, none has a left-side navigation menu.

Yes, I have an example (http://jsfiddle.net/tawani/EFhGL/embedded/result/) that is close to what I want but for some reason in IE10, everything is right-aligned.

Comment: Did you at least try by yourself a bit ? Please provie us with sone example of what you did, and we may help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">top nav</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">side bar</div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">content area</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to toss `-xs` in there too.

Comment: yup Eric you are right .. but i just wanted to give him the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a wrapper around the `sidebar` and `content` to acheive the 100% height and fixed sidebar like Gmail..

Here is an example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/82174

Comment: There sidebar of your example is not scrollable

Comment: It is now. Sorry, I missed that part in your question.